# What's the difference between 程 and 程度?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

What the difference between  程 and 程度?

I haven't been able to find any using my dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ほど is usually used as particle, whereas 程度 is a noun, e.g.

> B*ほど*Aの**程度**は大きくない。
>   A's **degree** is not *as* high *as* B's.

[ほど](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch/0/0ss/118151200000/) can be used as noun, but I would say [程度](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%A6) is more common. The dictionary definitions show that the meaning is not that different (e.g. 大辞泉 has 許容される限度。 for 程度; 大辞林 has 許される程度。限度。 for ほど).