How does 程度 fit in with ほど　and くらい？
According to this https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2397/65948
ほど is usually to the upper limit/degree but I would like to ask is it over what we proposed like in this sentence:
もう歩けないほど疲れた
Does this mean that I can’t walk or close to not being able to walk? Can ほど　be translated as “to the point that” but implying that we’re close to it, but still a slight margin away from it? Like taking that example above, can it be translated as:
I’m already tired to the point where I can’t even walk
To me, the English translation doesn’t say that I can still walk but maybe in some cases it can be used to me I can still walk but I’m just saying it to imply how tired I am.
For くらい, it means to the bottom limit/degree and in that link, it says it’s already over what we proposed but it’s just a bit over it, not over in a large margin.
Taking the same example:
もう歩けないくらい疲れた
Can くらい　be interpreted as “at the very least” cause the examples he gives certainly fits it. Is this translation close to the original intent:
I’m already tired that at the very least I can’t walk.
Now this sentence fits the original sentence very well IMO. It has the bottom limit and it doesn’t necessarily say it’s so bad that I can’t even stand up. I’m just listing the bare minimum thing that I can’t do. It vague and I think it fits quite well with くらい
Now what I want to ask about is 程度, where does it fit in? I don’t know if I should take this answer https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39189/65948 cause it’s 程度の instead of just 程度, I know くらい has the implication that it’s vague unlike 程度 but is 程度 just くらい without the vagueness?

Not an answer to our question, but I think you may be misinterpreting the もう here.  It seems like you are associating もう with 疲れた to get "already tired", but I think it is intended to go with 歩けない meaning "cannot walk anymore".

Both くらい and ほど are adverbs, but 程度 is a noun. You may use it as an adverb with the particle に though. 歩けない程度に疲れた. But that's WAY too formal and stiff. I'd expect 程度 (as an adverb) to be used in more formal writings/speeches, not daily conversations, unless as a noun meaning "degree". Btw, ほど can be written in Kanji as 程{ほど}, so that might shed some light on their relationship

So 程度 is just like ほど but the nuances are that 程度 as an adverb is usually used in formal situations and the other nuance is that it can imply the actual degree of the thing  but ほど can’t?

Yes. ほど is not used as a noun.
